# How to add utterances in LUIS app via LUIS programmatic API which contains list entities

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to add labelled utterances to the LUIS App which have list type of entities through the [Programmatic API(s)](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c08) provided by LUIS.

But, I cannot seem to understand how to send the request body.

Comment: Can you add more details of how you are trying to use the API? It's a POST request so you just have to set a body content according to the one in the documentation you provided

Comment: Mark an utterance via the UX for a list entity. Export your app. Look at the Json for that utterance to understand how the list entity is labeled.

Comment: @DFBerry The List entity array in the exported app is an empty JSON array.

Answer (score 2):

The [LUIS Programmatic APIs v2.0](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c08) has shared an example request body for us, and I can label entities in utterance using this API:

[image]

Besides, if you are a C# developer and you want to achieve it in C# project, you can find and try the C# code sample provided in LUIS Programmatic APIs documentation.

[image]

And I test the code with the following request body, which works for me.

```
var body = "{'text': 'give me some potatoes','intentName': 'findfood','entityLabels': [{'entityName': 'foodname','startCharIndex': 13,'endCharIndex': 21}]}";

// Request body
byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
```

Comment: This is only valid for simple entities, but how to do it list entities?

Comment: You only need to label machine learned entities. A list entity is an exact text match so you don't label it. You can add an utterance but don't add the label.

Comment: Yes, as DFBerry said, if your utterance that you want to add contains a list type entity, you do not need to explicitly label it.

Comment: In my above test, I use list type entity `foodname` and label it in utterance, which also works fine.

Comment: @DFBerry can you please elaborate more on your comment as an answer please.

Comment: You only need to label machine-learned entities. Other entities are found  by regex or text match. The table on this page notes entity types https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-concept-entity-types. Likewise you only need to train when a machine-learned entity or an intent has changed.

Comment: If I do this, I can see the utterance in the LUIS portal but the word "potatoes" does not appear highlighted as a ``foodname`` entity. Should this happen? Or should I expect to see it highlighted?